# Magento 2 : How to get admin user data in observer?

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml

I have observer of *backend_auth_user_login_success*.

I need the data of the admin user who is login in observer.

Can anyone please help me into this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By using `\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session` $authSession you can get the current logged in admin user details without the observer. Ex: `$this->authSession->getUser();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `events.xml` file here in your module

> app/code/Vendor\Module/etc/events.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="backend_auth_user_login_success">
        <observer name="backend_auth_user_login_success_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\BackendAuthObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now create Observer file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/BackendAuthObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class BackendAuthObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $user = $observer->getEvent()->getUser();

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/backend_auth_user_login_success.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($user->getData());

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Run below commands once

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Now Go to your Backend and try to login with your username and password, and navigate to your **var/log** directory you can see `backend_auth_user_login_success.log` file there with your user content.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Perfect answer. It helps lot. Thanks

Comment: @MayurSisodiya, Welcome Buddy. :-)